# Xdebug tracer irregularities when using namespaces / due to PHP optimization

Tags: php, xdebug

When I run an Xdebug trace on a PHP script without a namepsace, when calling "call_user_func" with a closure, there is no entry in the trace file for "call_user_func", but only the closure.

The same issue is seen when throwing an exception from PHP (call_user_func mentioned in the namepsaced code only).

When I add a namespace, then call_user_func is registered in the trace. Additionally, when using "defined" (a function), it will only register if the first parameter is not a constant. This seems optimization related.

Is there any way to turn off these optimizations and make it so that all function calls are logged to the trace file?

```
<?php

///namespace A;

$a = function(){

};
call_user_func($a, 1);
```

PHP + Xdebug test script

```
nano /tmp/1.php
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.overload_var_dump=0 -d display_errors=1 -d display_startup_errors=1 -d error_reporting=E_ALL -d xdebug.auto_trace=1 -d xdebug.trace_format=1 -d xdebug.trace_options=0 -d xdebug.collect_params=1 -d xdebug.collect_return=1 -d xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp -d xdebug.trace_output_name=trace /tmp/1.php
cat /tmp/trace.xt
```

Result with namepsace:

```
Version: 2.6.0
File format: 4
TRACE START [2018-08-13 03:39:44]
1   0   0   0.000062    353488  {main}  1       /tmp/1.php  0   0
2   1   0   0.000080    353808  call_user_func:{/tmp/1.php:8}   0       /tmp/1.php  8   2   class Closure   long
3   2   0   0.000085    353808  A\{closure} 1       /tmp/1.php  8   1   long
3   2   1   0.000088    353808
3   2   R           null
2   1   1   0.000090    353808
2   1   R           null
1   0   1   0.000092    353808
            0.000110    280
TRACE END   [2018-08-13 03:39:44]
```

Result without namespace

```
Version: 2.6.0
File format: 4
TRACE START [2018-08-13 03:41:02]
1   0   0   0.000064    353232  {main}  1       /tmp/1.php  0   0
2   1   0   0.000079    353552  {closure:/tmp/1.php:5-7}    1       /tmp/1.php  8   1   long
2   1   1   0.000083    353552
1   0   1   0.000085    353552
            0.000103    184
TRACE END   [2018-08-13 03:41:02]
```